# Where can I find the tissue-specific protein expression levels for hTERT (telomerase subunit)?

Tags: proteins, gene-expression, telomere

I find a number of contradictory sources regarding the tissues in which hTERT - the protein - is expressed. Does anybody know some resource that authoritatively (as authoritative or widely-accepted as is possible) lists the various tissues and hTERT's protein expression levels?

Any similar resource for gene expression of hTERT?

Answer (score 3):

I have found that biogps.org has all expression data I need:

https://biogps.org

https://biogps.org/#goto=genereport&id=7015

Comment: not heard of this before - just had a bit of a play and it does seem like a great tool!

Comment: Thanks but this is only gene expression. I'm talking of protein expression, which by no means correlates to gene expression. It's often assayed by immunohistochemistry with scaling up achieved with tissue microarrays